# async await makes my tasks slow while task.Start() runs them fast

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-table-storage

I am running 10k tasks which each send a batch of data to an Azure Storage Table.

If I use the first method below with async await that returns running tasks the tasks execute really slow and increasingly slower from a couple of seconds climbing up to 10, 100 seconds etc.

If I use the second method below that returns new running tasks they run really quickly! Just a very few tens of ms per task.

Why is there such a huge difference here? What am I missing?

At the end of my task creation I do a simple Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray()).

```
    private static async Task ExecuteBatch(TableBatchOperation tableBatchOperation, CloudTable cloudTable, TextWriter log)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    log.WriteLine("Committed " + tableBatchOperation.Count + " records in " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds.");
}

private static Task ExecuteBatch2(TableBatchOperation tableBatchOperation, CloudTable cloudTable, TextWriter log)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        cloudTable.ExecuteBatch(tableBatchOperation);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        log.WriteLine("Committed " + tableBatchOperation.Count + " records " + " in " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds.");
    });
}
```

aftger

Comment: In your second method you are not waiting for `cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation);` to complete, it just fires off and then continues.

Comment: Your second try is plain wrong. You measure the *starting* of the task, not it's *completion*.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I changed it to ExecuteBatch instead (the syncrounous version) and it's much slower. That was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you use `await` you are actually "awaiting" the result, so if you block on `ExecuteBatch`, it won't end till `ExcecuteBatchAsync` ends.

In the other hand, `ExecuteBatch2` does not "await" anything. Even if you block on the `ExecuteBatch2` response, the `ExecuteBatchAsync` operation is launched in parallel and `ExecuteBatch2` ends, despite of the task launched by `ExecuteBatchAsync` is still running.

**UPDATE:**

```
1|   var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
2|   await cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation);
3|   stopwatch.Stop();
4|   log.WriteLine("Committed " + tableBatchOperation.Count + " records in " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds.");
```

In the first method, because you are awaiting, you won't get to line #3 until line #2 ends.

However in your second method:

```
1|   var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
2|   cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation);
3|   stopwatch.Stop();
4|   log.WriteLine("Committed " + tableBatchOperation.Count + " records " + " in " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds.");
```

You will get from line #2 to line #3 immediately, because `ExecuteBatchAsync` is happening in parallel, nothing is making the thread block for a result. If you do `cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation).Wait()` you will probably get the same result than in the first method.

Comment: I know it's kind of simple and I know it's staring me in the face but I am still struggling a bit with the answer. await makes the async call block right there and only return when it's done. OK but I still get a long list of tasks that block for a long time in the Task.WaitAll() call. The second version ExecuteBatch2 works the way I thought the first version would.

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation.